# Change doc string summary of a function on the fly

Tags: doc-strings

Is it possible to change the first line of a docstring of a function, without editing the source code of this function? And if, how can I do this?

**Background:** some packages come with a pretty useless doc string summary.
(for example, `fci-mode`: "Toggle fci-mode on and off.").

Because I have some helper commands, which show this summary, I'd like to exchange the docstring summary of those functions to something more useful (or even translate them to my mother tongue), without touching the source code of those packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the raw documentation string of a function `foo` with `(documentation 'foo t)`.

You can set the documentation string of `foo` with
`(put 'foo 'function-documentation "My new docstring.")`.

The following example shows you how you can exchange the first line of the documentation string:

```el
(defun change-description-line (symbol new-description)
  "Change first line of doc string for SYMBOL to NEW-DESCRIPTION."
  (put symbol 'function-documentation
       (concat new-description
           (let* ((doc (documentation symbol t))
              (pos (cl-position ?\n doc)))
         (and pos (substring doc pos))))))

;;; Usage example:
(unintern 'foo obarray)
(defun foo ()
  "Greetings from function foo.
The real info often is on the second line:-(."
  )

(change-description-line 'foo "New description of foo.")
```

Note that the symbol property `function-documentation` overrides the documentation stored in the function object.

To restore the documentation from the function object you can use
`(put 'foo 'function-documentation nil)`

Alternatively, if you want to re-define `foo` anyway you can just remove the symbol `foo` from the global obarray:
`(unintern 'foo obarray)`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Tobias's answer, refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Accessing Documentation`

The other notable aspect of dynamic documentation via the `function-documentation` symbol property (amongst others), is that it can be *generated* on-demand.

> If FUNCTION is a symbol, this function first looks for the
>   ‘function-documentation’ property of that symbol; if that has a
>   non-‘nil’ value, the documentation comes from that value (**if the
>   value is not a string, it is evaluated**).

e.g. A `function-documentation` property value of `'(foo)` will cause the function `foo` to be called to obtain the documentation, each time it is needed.

Comment: very interesting