# Appending to function documentation

Tags: doc-strings

Can one append to a function documentation by calling some function or string in the documentation part?

With the following I do not get anything from `get`.

```
(defun myfunc 
  "Brief description"
...)

(put 'myfunc 'function-documentation
     (concat
      (get 'myfunc 'function-documentation)
      "Line 1
Line 2"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change doc string summary of a function on the fly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/change-doc-string-summary-of-a-function-on-the-fly)

Comment: @Tobias's answer there tells you how to change a function's doc string with Elisp, including how to prepend or append or replace part or all of it.

Comment: Reading it, it was about changing the first line of a docstring of a function.  I want something different.  Have one line from the function, then append a usage part defined before the function declaration.

Comment: It's the same thing. Replace the doc string with whatever string you want. Appending to the existing string is about the easiest change possible: `concat`.

Comment: Would be more useful for me to define the text before defining the function.  I would need some examples as I am struggling with Tobias 's answer.  I know about `concat` but not in what I got to de here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change doc string summary of a function on the fly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/change-doc-string-summary-of-a-function-on-the-fly) tells the whole story but maybe one point could do with a bit more emphasis: Emacs looks for documentation of the function `foo` in two different places:

1. The original doc-string in the definition of `foo`.  This is available from elisp as `(documentation 'foo t)`.
2. The contents of the `function-documentation` property of the symbol `foo`.

The second overrides the first when it is non-nil and the second is *not* initialised from the first.  Thus

```
(defun foo ()
  "Foo's original doc.")

(documentation 'foo t)  ;=> "Foo's original doc."

(get 'foo 'function-documentation)  ;=> nil
```

The OP wants to append to the original documentation so this will do the trick:

```
(put 'foo 'function-documentation
     (concat
      (documentation 'foo t)
      "Line 1
Line 2"))
```

Thus use `documentation` to pull out the original doc-string, `concat` stuff to it and store the result in the `function-documentation` property.